# Find 73 palindromes

Tags: scala, collections, binary, decimal, palindrome

I am trying to find 73 decimal numbers which binary representations are palindromes. I also need to get the sum of these numbers.
I am totally new to Scala, so I've been trying to create this function which defines palindromes and sums them up. The issue is that I do not really know how to combine it into one function and include that there should be 73 numbers.

I already have a simple function which defines palindromes:

```
def isPalindrome(someNumber: String): Boolean = someNumber.length > 1 && someNumber.reverse.mkString == someNumber
```

And I have made some kind of a blueprint for my main function. I try to write all the found palindromic numbers into the list (so I could use some filters later):

```
def findPalindromes(list: List[Int]): Int = {
  for(i <- 0 to 100){
    if(isPalindrome(Integer.toBinaryString(i))) {
      (xs: List[Int]) => i :: xs
    }
    sum(list)
  }
}
```

I know some collections functions, but I don't have much experience using them. So I will be grateful if you could explain to me which collections and functions can be used in this case.
I would be very grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: The loop assumes that there exists 73 palindromes between 0 and 100. Perhaps it may make a little more sense to have a count, called palindromes. And perhaps you can make the exit condition `while (count < 73)`. within the loop you can increment `count++` when `isPalindrom()` returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` and `take` could be used here instead of looping.

`filter` will add an element to a new collection that is returned based on the predicate you pass it. In your case it is `isPalindrome`

`take` can be used get `n` elements from a collection. i.e. the first 73 elements from the ones that passed the filter.

So, if you chain these together you get:

```
def findPalindromes(list: List[Int]): Int = {
  list.filter(x => isPalindrome(Integer.toBinaryString(x))).take(73).sum
}
```

You could pass in something like `Range(1, 10000).toList`. Another improvement could be to make this stop when it finds 73 palindromes instead of finding all of them and taking the first 73. A simple counter could be used for that or a `Stream`

The `Stream` version is rather elegant:

```
def findPalindromes(n: Int) = Stream.from(1).filter(x => isPalindrome(Integer.toBinaryString(x))).take(n)
```

Force the evaluation of the `Stream` with `sum`:

`scala> findPalindromes(73).sum
res10: Int = 35619`

Comment: This answer is great, but I am not sure whether a sum is a right number. It looks too small. Do you know where I can check such numbers which binary representation is a palindrome?

Comment: You can test it with your own code. `val pals = Range(1,10000).filter(x => isPalindrome(Integer.toBinaryString(x)))` will give you palindromes then use `forall` to verify `pals.forall(p => Integer.toBinaryString(p).equals(Integer.toBinaryString(p).reverse))`

Answer (score 2):

Your blueprint is good. Just don't assume that the first 73 palindromes exist within the first 100 integers. You could even start at a negative number because it is possible that its binary representation is a palindrome. For simplicity, I will start at 0, looking for the first 73 positive palindromes. Sorry, I don't know Scala, I know Java. The algorithm would be the same.

Output:

```
...
341 is a palindrome
341 in binary is 101010101

349 is a palindrome
349 in binary is 101011101

357 is a palindrome
357 in binary is 101100101

sum:9245
```

The Code:

```
public class Palindrome {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count;
    int sum;
    int i;

    count = 0;
    sum = 0;

    // Start at integer 0
    i = 0;

    // Loop until we count 73 palindromes
    while (count < 73) {

      if (isPalindrome(i)) {
        System.out.println(i + " is a palindrome");
        System.out.println(i + " in binary is " + Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        System.out.println();

        // Increment the sum
        sum += i;

        // Incrememnt the counter
        count++;
      }

      // Increment the index
      i++;
    }

    System.out.println("sum:" + sum);

  }

  public static boolean isPalindrome(int n) {

    // By default, we assumt the String to be a palindrome
    boolean palindrome = true;
    String string;
    int length;

    // Convert to binary
    string = Integer.toBinaryString(n);

    // Get length of string
    length = string.length();

    // Loop half way into the string
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2 - 1; i++) {

      // Compare the ith character from beginning of string
      // to the ith character going from the end of stirng
      if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(length-i-1)) {

        // If they are not equal, set boolean to false, and break
        palindrome = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return palindrome;
  }
}
```

Comment: Java does like to make some things complicated :)  `def isPalindrome(x:Int) = {val s = x.toBinaryString; s == s.reverse}`

Comment: Haha for sure, I'm sure there are some functions that can do some of the work for you. It kinda sounded like a homework assignment, so I wrote it out in full. Its like if your HW is to sort numbers and you call Arrays.sort(), whats the point? haha, but yes, Java gets pretty verbose